Translate mui Data Grid column headers
I use MUI Data Grid froa table and now I am working on i18n localization. I encountered a trouble where I can't translate column headers due to them being a static object and not a react component. Applying t hook doesnt work on lanuage change. How can I change translation when triggering language change?
Here's the file which I export to table react component file and use in column props.
import { Box, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import {
  deliverTruckBulk,
  pickupTruckBulk,
} from "assets/img/statuses/statusImages";
import { dateComparator, localizeDate, localizeTime } from "helpers/helpers";
import i18next from "i18next";
import StatusIcon from "../../../../StatusIcon/StatusIcon";
import {
  OrderTableCaption,
  OrderTableText,
} from "../../../../Typography/OrderList";

// const t = (string) => i18next.t(string);

export const OrderTableColumns = [
  {
    field: "shippingDate",
    headerName: "Requested Date",
    sortComparator: dateComparator,
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <Box>
        <OrderTableText sx={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>
          {localizeDate(params.value.date)}
        </OrderTableText>
        <OrderTableCaption>
          {`${localizeTime(params.value.startTime)} - ${localizeTime(
            params.value.endTime
          )}`}
        </OrderTableCaption>
      </Box>
    ),
    flex: 0,
  },
  {
    field: "po-order",
    headerName: i18next.t("order.orderNumber"),
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <Box>
        <OrderTableText>{params.value.customerReference}</OrderTableText>
        <OrderTableCaption>{params.value.orderNumber}</OrderTableCaption>
      </Box>
    ),
    flex: 1,
    sortable: false,
  },
  {
    field: "destination",
    headerName: "Destination",
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <OrderTableText>{params.value.siteName}</OrderTableText>
        <OrderTableCaption>{params.value.street}</OrderTableCaption>
      </Box>
    ),
    flex: 1,
    sortable: false,
  },
  {
    field: "material",
    headerName: "Material",
    renderCell: (params) => <OrderTableText>{params.value}</OrderTableText>,
    flex: 1,
    sortable: false,
  },
  {
    field: "ordered-delivered",
    headerName: "Ordered/Delivered",
    renderCell: ({ value }) => {
      const isShippingTypeCollect = value.shippingType === "collect";
      const shippingType = isShippingTypeCollect
        ? pickupTruckBulk
        : deliverTruckBulk;

      const tooltipTitle = `${
        isShippingTypeCollect ? "Pick-up" : "Delivery"
      } by bulk carrier`;

      return (
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", columnGap: "5px" }}>
          <OrderTableText>
            {value.quantity} {i18next.t("capacityTons1")}
          </OrderTableText>
          <Tooltip title={tooltipTitle}>
            <img src={shippingType} alt={shippingType} width="24px" />
          </Tooltip>
        </Box>
      );
    },
    flex: 0,
    sortable: false,
  },
  {
    field: "status",
    headerName: i18next.t("order.orderStatus"),
    renderCell: (params) => <StatusIcon status={params.value} />,
    flex: 0,
    maxWidth: 60,
    sortable: false,
  },
];


Maybe you can move the headers declaration inside a component or a hook to get access to t?

I have access to t. But it doesnt work since the object is not dynamically refreshed. I can't move it to the component for refactoring reasons. It would bloat up the file.

import { t } from 'i18next';
t('schema:evaluateWaves.requireProof')
Try again, if you change the language, the column headers in OrderTableColumns will also be changed because it is imported in the components (as usual). If it does not change the language, I think you should check your locales, en, vi, i18n folder structure (Try setting i18n to another language by default to see if it works).

The thing is that the translation works by itself. But the text in headers doesn't change. I can't import the hook there since it's not a functional component. I guess I'll have to refactor it into component somehow.

Maybe you can turn OrderTableColumns into a function so it will recalculate on re-render instead of being static and stuck on the first language

Moved column object into a custom hook where I got the access to t hook from i18n. Futher refactor required but at lteast it works.
